# Is there an equivalent to the node-png module which will install on windows?

Tags: node.js

The [node-png](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-png) module currently cannot be used on windows. (Due to reliance on node-waf I think).

**Is there a module with equivalent functionality (for creating pngs, async) which is NPM installable on windows?**

I've seen [png-sync](https://npmjs.org/package/png-sync), which says it's windows compatible, but I would like to keep everything async.

Comment: I'm fond of LearnBoost's [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas), which uses `node-gyp` now AFAIK. It's got a dependency on [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/download/), which is available for Windows, so it should be possible in theory. I haven't tried, though, so YMMV!

Answer (score 2):

[node-pngjs](https://github.com/niegowski/node-pngjs) (Simple PNG encoder/decoder for Node.js with no native dependencies) should be windows compatible, since it has no native dependencies. Because it is pure JavaScript, it might be a bit slower though.

I cannot test this on Windows unfortunately.